# Binding DataTemplate Column BackGround Color to IvalueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a WPF datagrid and have a datatemplate column called "Requested Date Out Source."
The application should look at the date in the cell and change the color based on if it's today, past, or future.

I have the Ivalueconverter:

```
public class FBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string input = value as string;
            {
                if (input == "Select a date")
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime(input);
                    switch (true)
                    {
                        case true when (dt == DateTime.Today):
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                        case true when (dt < DateTime.Today):
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        case true when (dt > DateTime.Today):
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                        default:
                            //return Brushes.Black;
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

I have the XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DateoutSource" Header="Requested &#x0a; Date Out Source" Width="125" SortMemberPath="DateOutSource" SortDirection="Ascending" >
                       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                       
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker x:Name="BtnDateOutSource" SelectedDate="{Binding DateOutSource}" SelectedDateChanged="BtnDateOutSource_SelectedDateChanged" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FBrushConverter}}">                               
                            </DatePicker>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The result is that the column is always red:

[image]

Tracing through the code indicates that the Convert Object value is always NULL which is why the display is always red.

This implies some issues with the binding.  I have tried a variety of approaches with no luck.

Any ideas on this one?
Thanks in Advance,
Kerry

Comment: Have you checked the actual type of `value` when you debug the converter? The Foreground Binding doesn't have any property path, so `value` is certainy the row item object, not a string.

Comment: Trace yields this:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
 BindingExpression path error: 'ForeGround' property not found on 'object' ''SourceInspection_30F8E31406EADA6CF79EEC6BB6AC8AE92DC21D809F1D3329238470B5A1906414' (HashCode=38811664)'. BindingExpression:Path=ForeGround; DataItem='SourceInspection_30F8E31406EADA6CF79EEC6BB6AC8AE92DC21D809F1D3329238470B5A1906414' (HashCode=38811664); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name='BtnDateOutSource'); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')


Value is null, no type.  Type is System.Windows.Media.Brush, the parameter is null.

Comment: No need for any of the names in your example, you also handle date changed while you have SelectedDate bound to a property. Also how do you populate `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `Foreground` property to `DateOutSource` property as suggested by @Xiaoy312:

```
Foreground="{Binding DateOutSource, Converter={StaticResource FBrushConverter}}"
```

Then you also need to modify your converter to cast the value to a `DateTime?` which I assume is the actual type of `DateOutSource`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)value;
    if (!dt.HasValue)
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    DateTime date = dt.Value.Date;
    if (date == DateTime.Today)
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    else if (date < DateTime.Today)
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    else if (date > DateTime.Today)
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the value to the converter, otherwise the current datacontext will be used as value which is likely not a `DateTime`:

```
Foreground="{Binding DateOutSource, Converter={StaticResource FBrushConverter}}"
```

Comment: @Kerry If you put a breakpoint on `string input = value as string;`, what is the value of `value`?